# Visual studio 2017 missing fonts colors options after update

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I just installed visual studio 15.7.4 and I lost options on the Fonts & Colors list.

[Visual Studio Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXPnR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just noticed some extensions needed updating after the Visual Studio upgrade. I updated said extensions and everything's working now.